# Nested Looping in OpenMP with unshared outer loop

Tags: for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp, nested-loops

I am trying to parallelize prefix sum with open mp.My code is

```
int a ,rem,d;
#pragma omp parallel private (a,rem,d)
for( d =0 ; d < N ; ++d) //need not parallelize
{

    #pragma omp barrier
    #pragma omp for
    for (int k = 1; k <= size ; ++k) //has to be parallelized
    {

        a = k + (2 ^ (d+1))-1;
        rem = a % (2^d);
        if ( rem == 0 && a <= size)
        {
            b = k;
            first[a]+= first[b];

        }

    }
}
```

I am getting a floating exception error when I run the code . I believe the error is in the int rem when I use the value of d. Could someone please help me. After each value of d the threads have to be snchronized so I have used pragma barrier.

Comment: I solved this issue by making the following  change :

<code >

int a,rem,d,b;
    
    for( d =0 ; d < N ; ++d) //need not parallelize
    {
        
        #pragma omp barrier
        #pragma omp parallel for private (a,rem,d)
        for (int k = 1; k <= size ; ++k) //has to be parallelized
        {
            
            a = k + (2 ^ (d+1))-1;
            rem = a % (2 ^ (d+1));
            if ( rem == 0 && a <= size)
            {
                b = k + (2 ^ (d))-1;
                first[a]+= first[b];
                
            }
            
        }
    }

<code>

Comment: Mine solution was wrong and sorry I am unable to delete it

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you get floating-point exceptions in a code that only uses integer variables?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is trivial. There was no error in parallelizing. The error was in the power function . In c ^ refers to XOR. I changed it to pow(2,d) and it worked perfectly fine